# Powershell vs Batch - Java command line

Tags: java, windows, powershell, batch-file

I used to launch a java tool with a batch like this :

```
java -classpath "./lib/JSanExport.jar;./lib/JSanRmiApiEx.jar;./lib/JSanRmiServerUx.jar" -Xms128M -Xmx768M -Dmd.command=command_VSPLA.txt -Dmd.logpath=log sanproject.getmondat.RJMdMain
```

For some reasons i need to convert that batch into a Powershell script. But when I copy the same line on my powershell script I got an error, whereas I launch it in the same workingdir.

```
c:\Program Files\ExportTool\export>powershell .\Run_VSPLA.ps1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /command=command_VSPLA/txt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .command=command_VSPLA.txt
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: .command=command_VSPLA.txt.  Program will exit.
```

Do you know what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set jvm options before classpath :

```
java -Xms128M -Xmx768M -Dmd.command=command_VSPLA.txt -Dmd.logpath=log  -classpath "./lib/JSanExport.jar;./lib/JSanRmiApiEx.jar;./lib/JSanRmiServerUx.jar" sanproject.getmondat.RJMdMain
```

It searches for class named /command=command_VSPLA/txt. For batch `=` is a delimiter and is parsed in a different way than powershell.

**EDIT**

The solution given by the OP:

```
java -Xms128M -Xmx768M "-Dmd.command=.\command_VSPLA.txt" "-Dmd.logpath=log" -classpath "./lib/JSanExport.jar;./lib/JSanRmiApiEx.jar;./lib/JSanRmiServerUx.jar" sanproject.getmondat.RJMdMain
```

Comment: You got no other idea? :(

Comment: You can try with `start-process` cmdlet and separate string for arguments : http://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html  .That way you should have more control over the parameters...

Comment: Didnt work but helped me a lot :) Here is the solution if you can edit your answer i'll give it as accepted:
java -Xms128M -Xmx768M "-Dmd.command=.\command_VSPLA.txt" "-Dmd.logpath=log" -classpath "./lib/JSanExport.jar;./lib/JSanRmiApiEx.jar;./lib/JSanRmiServerUx.jar" sanproject.getmondat.RJMdMain

Comment: ahaa.Great work.Quotes prevent jvm options to be taken as two different parameters.Should thought for this myself :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seem like it can't find command_VSPLA.txt, maybe try a full path.

Comment: Dosn't change anything :

c:\Program Files\ExportTool\export>powershell .\Run_VSPLA.ps1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /command=C:\Program Files\ExportTool\export\command_VSPLA/txt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .command=C:\Program Files\ExportTool\export\command_VSPLA.txt
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        (...)at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: .command=C:\Program Files\ExportTool\export\command_VSPLA.txt.  Program will exit.